# How to move one file to a folder using terminal?

Tags: command-line

I want to move one file to a folder using terminal. How do I do this?

Comment: http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php Check out the `mv` command.

Comment: use the mv command. It might be more complicated as you may have problems with ownership / permissions if you have moving a file outside of $HOME.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy or move a file from a folder to desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797097/how-to-copy-or-move-a-file-from-a-folder-to-desktop)

Comment: @muru: That question is distinctly different because it's asking how to move files to the desktop specifically.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

```
mv [file] [directory]
```

For example, to move `info.txt` from the actual directory into the `config/` directory, type `mv info.txt config/`

---

As was pointed out in a correct comment, the above will fail if the user running the command doesn't have write access to either the file or the folder.

If you prefix the command with `sudo`, you are telling the system to run the command as the `root` user (similar to an Admin account). Example:

```
sudo mv info.txt config/
```

***BIG IMPORTANT NOTE:***
Only use `sudo` if you are sure you know what you're doing - Ubuntu protects things for a reason.  Using `sudo` you can break your OS, forcing a reinstall, if you move (or delete or whatever) important files.

Comment: depends on the ownership and permissions of the destination. Might need to use sudo or discuss ownership / permissions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the same command for renaming files. A rename is essentially moving a file to the same location but with a new name. Using the previous example:

```
mv info.txt config/information.txt
```

This would move the file and change its name.