# How to copy or move a file from a folder to desktop?

Tags: command-line, desktop-directories

I am a beginner and I want to copy/move a file from a specific folder to the desktop. I use `cp` and `mv` for those tasks. But I want to copy/move to the desktop.

Say I want to move `file1` to Desktop, I use

mv file1 _____

In _____,

1. I used Desktop, but it renames the file to "Desktop".
2. I used home/Desktop but it says no file/folder is found.

Answer (score 18):

Desktop is a directory in your user's home directory.

If your language is English it is called `Desktop`.

To copy some `file` there, you can run

```
cp file ~/Desktop
```

`~` stands for `/home/<username>`

If your UI language is not English, it is called differently.

You can do a copy without finding the correct name by

```
cp file "$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)"
```

You can get the name of the Desktop directory by

```
xdg-user-dir DESKTOP
```

You can use `mv` instead of `cp` if you want to move a file instead of copying.

Comment: Thank you dude...By the way what this command "xdg-user-dir DESKTOP" actually implies?

Comment: It shows the path to the desktop directory. You can run `man xdg-user-dir` for more info.

Answer (score 8):

How these commands work depends on **where you are** in the filesystem.

You can normally see where you are from your prompt:

```
zanna@monster:~/Desktop$
```

That's my prompt when the *current working directory* is `~/Desktop`, the handy shortcut for `/home/zanna/Desktop`

If you're not sure where you are, you can type `pwd` and get the full *absolute path*

```
zanna@monster:~/Desktop$ pwd
/home/zanna/Desktop
```

The first `/` is important - that's the root directory, and all full absolute paths will start with it

You can use *absolute* or *relative* paths to do things with files. If you are in the directory where the file you want to move is, to move to your desktop, assuming your desktop directory is actually called `Desktop` (don't forget that **Linux is case sensitive**)

```
mv file1 ~/Desktop
```

because the current working directory is assumed.

From anywhere in your filesystem you can do this:

```
mv /path/to/file1 ~/Desktop
```

but replace /path/to with the real path! for example, if the file is in you home Downloads folder do

```
mv ~/Downloads/file1 ~/Desktop
```

`mv` also renames files... if the target is a file that exists and isn't a directory, `mv` overwrites it with the contents of the first file, and renames to the target. If the file doesn't exist, then `file1` is renamed as the target without overwriting anything, as you discovered.

To copy a file instead of moving it, you can do exactly the same as above, with `cp` instead of `mv`. Only the behaviour is different in this case - the original `file1` continues to exist in its previous location.

To learn more, you can check `man mv` and `man cp`

A nice option for learning - you can get `mv` and `cp` to tell you what they are doing by making them verbose: adding `-v`. Here I move the file `chocolate` from the current working directory `~/playground` to my Desktop with the verbose option, and I get some output in the terminal:

```
zanna@monster:~/playground$ mv -v chocolate ~/Desktop
'chocolate' -> '/home/zanna/Desktop/chocolate'
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `mv file1 ~/Desktop` for moving and `cp file1 ~/Desktop` for copying to your `Desktop` directory.

Comment: If locale is not English, the name may be not Desktop.

Comment: Good point. Any way to generalize to any locale?

Comment: If we know the DE, then yes.

Comment: @edwinksl Perhaps there's an XDG variable that points to it? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_user_directories

Comment: @adi FYI the `~` symbol is shorthand for `/home/yourusername` (for example, if my username is "Nick", `~/Desktop` and `/home/nick/Desktop` are synonyms for the exact same directory)

Comment: @NickWeinberg I am not quite sure this works in all DE.

Comment: @Pilot6 It should work in any DE that conforms to the FreeDesktop.org specifications, which includes all of the major ones (and many of the minor ones), I think

Answer (score 2):

To move file1 from somedir to your desktop:

```
cd /somedir
mv -i file1 "$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)"
```

To copy the file instead:

```
cd /somedir
cp -i file1 "$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)"
```

The -i stands for "interactive." It will cause the move and copy commands to prompt you before overwriting any existing file.